# Why doesn't accessing this nullpointer cause an exception?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass() {
        std::cout << "TestClass instantiated\n";
    }

    ~TestClass() {
        std::cout << "TestClass destructed\n";
    }

    void PrintSomething() {
        std::cout << "TestClass is printing something\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    
    TestClass* tClass = new TestClass();
    delete tClass;
    tClass = nullptr;
    tClass->PrintSomething();

    std::cout << "Exiting...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
TestClass instantiated
TestClass destructed
TestClass is printing something
Exiting...
```

I thought that trying to print something after the tClass pointer had been set to nullptr would cause a nullpointer exception error, but it prints just fine.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is undefined, anything can happen. A possible explanation is in the linked duplicate.

Comment: There are no "null pointer exceptions" in the C++ standard. Perhaps you're basing your expectations on some other language?

Comment: When a program crashes, sometimes the operation system reports the problem as an "exception". That's not the same thing as a C++ exception. In C++ you get an exception when you `throw` it. Interestingly, Java doesn't have pointers, but it does have a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The language does not detect nullptr misuse for you.  C++ is not a nanny language.  You need to check if a potentially nullptr pointer is a nullptr before dereferencing it.  Just before `tClass->PrintSomething();` add this line `if (tClass == nullptr) throw std::logic_error("nullptr");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't accessing this nullpointer cause an exception?

Because it's not specified to cause an exception. Accessing through a null poitner results in undefined behaviour. Don't do it.